# Separate ReactJS app versus integrating with backend

Tags: reactjs

Regarding of what backend you use to power the API behind a React app (Ruby on Rails, Node.js/Express, Java, etc), what are the consequences of making the frontend React app separate repository?

I like the idea of having my ReactJS  app separated from my backend API code, just want to understand the pros/cons of going with this approach.

Comment: [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/73574)

Answer (score 0):

---

### pros

---

1. front-end devs doesnt have to get familiar with backend
2. You can choose not to show your *secret recipe*.
3. can upgrade and deploy one without the other
4. Code Reusablity
5. Lazy loading for better UX

*I actually dont have any cons to tell about this. it's just that i feel right developing apps like this. installing npm packages in `RoR` felt so wrong.*

Answer (score 0):

**more Pros -**

1. You new separate UI can link to more backends than 1 - think centralized UI for disparate components
2. Like Angular more, bang you got it
3. Like React more than Angular, bang  you got it

**Cons -**

1. Needs added work to setup CORs
2. You will probably have to cookup secret sauce for pagination, serialization (i.e tied together even though separate) - not a problem if you follow a standard anyway
3. Need to have a long deep thought on behaviour when the backkend is down
4. Need to wrap brain around pull vs push
5. You now have 2 diff OS stacks & TCP stacks in the picture to increase your work on sys admin patching & understanding latency between the components
6. wrap brain around state & its management

IMHO separating the UI is worth all the cons given the pros outlined here & by Shan